# It is possible to overload `??` operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, null-coalescing-operator

I read this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) regarding the operator overloading.

In that example, the operators used were `+`, `-` and also can define others `*` or `/`.

I want to overload `??` operator to be used for strings like

```
string emptyString = emptyString ?? "OtherValue";
```

instead of

```
string emptyString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(emptyString) ? "OtherValue" : emptyString;
```

I **don't** want to convert string to object and compare using `??`.

I know that `??` is used for nullable value types, what MSDN says:

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types.
>
> It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

I want to ask you **if is possible** to overload this operator in C#. The above example is a simple situation when need to use `??`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Please take a look here [Overloadable Operators C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) . Section 'These operators cannot be overloaded.'

Answer (score 7):

No you can't.

A simple workaround would be to use an extension method:

```
 public static string IfNullOrEmpty(this string instance, string alt){
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(instance) ? alt : instance;
 }

 var str1 = "".IfNullOrEmpty("foo"); //'foo'
 var str2 = ((string)null).IfNullOrEmpty("bar"); //'bar'
 var str3 = "Not null or empty".IfNullOrEmpty("not used"); //'not null or empty'
```

Although note that I've found that in order for the extension method to appear on first-class compile-time constants such as `""` you need to merge that extension method into `System`; i.e:

```
 namespace System {
   public static class MyStringExtensions { 
     // method here
   }
 }
```

***Don't do this - but just for kicks***

You *could* - although I wouldn't recommend it - write a wrapper type for `String` which contains implicit cast operators to and from `string` which return `null` if the string is empty - thus using the `??` operator on instances of that type would yield the correct behaviour:

```
    public class FakeString
    {
        private string _source;
        public FakeString(string source)
        {
        }

        public static implicit operator string(FakeString instance)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(instance._source) ? null : instance._source;
        }

        public static implicit operator FakeString(string source)
        {
            return new FakeString(source);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        FakeString fs = "";
        string result = (string)fs ?? "foo";

        Assert.AreEqual("foo", result);
    }
```

However, has you can see - you have to use casting to kick off the conversion and really it's pretty ugly and horrible and, well, just don't do it.  But you *could*.  *I* wouldn't.

Do I need any more disclaimers?

**A little note on that explicit cast**

A big part of me thought that `string result = fs ?? foo;` should work but it does not.  The reason being that the `null` check performed by `??` is on the reference on the left-hand side only - it's type agnostic except in the case of a nullable value type.  Decompiling the IL, the reference is simply loaded onto the stack and then checked to see if it evaluates to true or false, the code branches at that point into one of two further operations that load a value onto the stack (which is where the `FakeString` operator then gets called).  This behaviour is not the same for a nullable value type - the compiler has knowledge of those, and so changes its behaviour accordingly.

Comment: I thought also for an extension for string.

Comment: Maybe instead of `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(instance) ? alt : string;` should be `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(instance) ? alt : instance;`

Comment: yep - whoops! I was up late listening to the tennis last night - doing an SO answer on 4 hours sleep isn't great

Answer (score 2):

Acc to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you cannot overload ?? operator.